# Need help with formal proofs of two simple theorems in the language of ZFC?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**EDIT: Starting Over**

I would like to see a formal proof in the language of ZFC of:

> 1. $\neg\exists S: \forall x:[x\in S \iff x\notin x]$
> 2. $\forall S: \exists x: x\notin S$  (added later)

Can someone list the *formal* proof here if it is not too long, or give me a reference, preferably online?

Comment: What do you mean by a "formal ZFC proof"? (And why do I have the feeling that you're going to post a link to your blog here?)

Comment: If it could be translated into ZFC by anybody who has existed since its invention, do you think we'd still be using ZFC?

Comment: You have forgotten the leading existential quantifier; thus the proof must conclude with : $\lnot \exists y \forall x ( x \in y \leftrightarrow x \notin x)$. As you have showed it is provable in f-o logic with the binary predicate $\in$. *Per se* it is not "paradoxical" att all... unless you consider the "naive" *Comprehension principle* as an axiom.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have put in the missing quantifier. Thanks. I'm just wondering what the formal proof would like. What is line 1 and by  what axiom of ZFC can we state it. What is line 2, and so on. It can't be that long.  4 or 5 lines at most.

Comment: @Hayden It would only prove ZFC inconsistent if such a set could be proven to exist. I am trying to prove the opposite: that, using ZFC, it does *not* exist. Is natural deduction not used in ZFC? Can I not tentatively assume the existence of this set? I am not stating it as a theorem.

Comment: @DanChristensen Yes, I realized what you really wanted when I saw Mauro's comment.  I'm not really sure how often natural deduction is used as the proof calculus (in everything I've read/seen used a Hilbert system).  But yes, by the Deduction Theorem you can show that assuming the existence of the set to derive a contradiction can be transformed into a formal proof of the set's nonexistence from the axioms of ZFC.

Comment: @Hayden Where might I find such a strictly formal proof in ZFC?

Comment: @DanChristensen I'm not sure where you'd find one, but to make one you'd need to decide what you want your axioms to actually be.  Once you've done this, you really just need to fill in the axioms used and probably some intermediate logical theorems depending on your axioms, but you've got the essential steps there.

Comment: @Hayden  *MY* axioms? I want to use the standard ZFC axioms -- nothing more, nothing less. Is there really no authoritative source I can go to for a formal proof of $\neg\exists S: \forall x:[x\in S \iff x\notin x]$ in the language of ZFC?

Comment: Isn't $x \notin x$ the same as the axiom of foundation?

Comment: It would be kind of weird if one of the paradoxes that motivated the creation of ZFC could be demonstrated in ZFC.

Comment: Removed all references to Russell or paradoxes.

Comment: Added a second theorem.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish: No, much weaker.

Comment: @DanChristensen While even the ZFC axioms do vary depending on the source, I meant more along the lines of the logical axioms.  Of course, the easiest approach would be to simply add in whatever logical axioms you need and not worry about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 1, this is a derivation with *Natural Deduction*.

Consider a first-order language with a binary *predicate* $E(x,y)$ :

1)  $(∃y)(∀x)(E(x,y) ↔ ¬E(x,x))$ --- assumed [b]

2) $(∀x)(E(x,s) ↔ ¬E(x,x))$ --- assumed [a] for $\exists$-elimination

3) $E(s,s) ↔ ¬E(s,s)$ --- from 2) by $\forall$-elimination

The formula in 3) is a contradiction, since $E(s,s) ↔ E(s,s)$. Thus, we have :

4) $\bot$ --- from 3)

5) $\bot$ --- from 4) by $\exists$-elimination, discharging [a] : $s$ does not occur in 5)

6) $(∃y)(∀x)(E(x,y) ↔ ¬E(x,x)) \to \bot$ --- from 1) and 5) by $\to$-introduction, discharging [a]

> $\vdash \lnot (∃y)(∀x)(E(x,y) ↔ ¬E(x,x))$ --- from 6) by *abbreviation* : $\lnot p := p \to \bot$.

We have used **no** $\mathsf {ZFC}$ axioms.

---

Ref to :

- George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory : Volume 2, Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=nparMXao59QC&pg=PA121) (2003), page 121.

---

---

Regarding 2, this formula is not *valid*.

Consider again the formula of first-order language with the binary *predicate* $E(x,y)$ :

> $∀y∃x\lnot E(x,y)$.

If we interpret it into the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers with $E$ interpreted as $\ge$, we have :

> $∀y∃x(x < y)$

that is clearly **not** satisfied for $y=0$.

Thus, being not *valid*, it is not provable by rules of logic alone, i.e. :

> > $\nvdash ∀y∃x\lnot E(x,y)$.

---

In presence of the *Axiom Schema of Separation*, we can use the Russell's paradox argument to prove that the assumption :

> $\exists y \forall x(x \in y)$

produces a contradiction. Simplifying a little :

1) $\exists y \forall x(x \in y)$ --- assumed [a]

2) $\forall x(x \in V)$ --- assumed [b] for $\exists$-elimination

3) $x \in V$ --- from 3) by $\forall$-elimination

4) $\mathsf {ZFC} \vdash \exists z \forall x (x \in z \leftrightarrow x \in V \land x \notin x)$ --- *Axiom of Separation*

5) $(x \in z \leftrightarrow x \in V \land x \notin x)$ --- from 4), assuming [c] : $\forall x (x \in z \leftrightarrow x \in V \land x \notin x)$ for $\exists$-introduction and by $\forall$-elimination

6) $(x \in z \leftrightarrow x \notin x)$ --- from 3) and 5) by *tautological implication*

7) $\exists z \forall x (x \in z \leftrightarrow x \notin x)$ --- from 6) by $\forall$-introduction : $x$ not *free* in assumptions [a], [b] or [c] and from 4) and 5) by $\exists$-elimination : $z$ not free in 7), discharging [c]

8) $\vdash \lnot \exists z \forall x (x \in z \leftrightarrow x \notin x)$ --- proved above

9) $\bot$ --- from 7) and 8)

10) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 2) by $\exists$-elimination : $V$ not free in 10), discharging [b]

11) $\exists y \forall x(x \in y) \to \bot$ --- from 1) and 10) by $\to$-introduction, discharging [a]

> $\mathsf {ZFC} \vdash \lnot \exists y \forall x(x \in y)$ --- from 11) by *abbreviation*.

Thus, we have concluded with :

> > $\mathsf {ZFC} \vdash\forall y \exists x(x \notin y)$.

Comment: Looks good. This is roughly how I did it my own system. I'm just wondering what you meant by "not a first-order theorem."

Comment: @DanChristensen - you can read any good textbook of Math Log... For example, Tourlakis, page 37 for **I.3.16 Definition ($\Gamma$-Theorems)** and the "special case with $\Gamma= \emptyset$ : "We often say in this case [$\vdash A$] that $A$ is provable with no *nonlogical axioms*."

Comment: This distinction doesn't seem like anything the would concern most mathematicians, but your proof is just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two Proofs in ZFC that the Russell ``Set" is not a set.

(1) The axiom of regularity states: $\forall x ( x \neq \emptyset \rightarrow \exists y \in x\ ( x \cap y = \emptyset) )$. If we had a set $R = \{x: x \notin x\}$ then consider now $\{R\}$. We see that there must be an element of $\{R\}$ which is disjoint from $\{R\}$. Since the only element of $\{R\}$ is R, it must be that $R \cap \{R\} = \emptyset$. So, since $R \in \{R\}$, we cannot have $R \in R$ (by the definition of disjoint).

(2) If we had a set $R = \{x: x \notin x\}$ then $R \in R$ $\leftrightarrow$ $R \notin R$. By the bi-valence of 1st-order classical logic, we must have either $R \in R$ or $R \notin R$. Since in either we case we have contradictions, and contradictions are not coherent in 1st-order classical-logic, since they would entail the truth of every sentence in the language of ZFC, we reject the existence of $R$.

Comment: Thanks, but while these look like quite rigorous proofs, I was looking for a purely formal proof, e.g. just a numbered list of formal statements citing the one axiom used to generate each statement. Something that could be verified by a computer. Is this not how formal proofs are written in the literature?